# K-Means Clustering in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, import, dataset, k-means

I am trying to implement K-means clustering from TensorFlow.
I already referred to this link
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans
-This is using random numbers in two dimensional array.

- How can I use dataset and convert to tensor objects and train data using kmeans?

Comment: Please include a minimal example of what you've tried and where it has gone wrong.  The example you linked shows how to do what you're asking, if you're failing to adapt it to your own solution, that is the actual problem.